# How to known if apache request is for directory or file?

Tags: apache-2.2

Let's say I enter `http://www.mywebsite.com:4048/cgi-bin` in URL. How do I if user is requesting a directory or a file?

Comment: The user is requesting a resource located in that URL. What it actually is on the web server, depends completely on how the web server is set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, your user is requesting a **file** with the name `cgi-bin` in this case. A request to a directory with the same name would read `http://www.mywebsite.com:4048/cgi-bin/` (so with a trailing slash)

**HOWEVER:**

You would want to configure your webserver to handle such a request for `cgi-bin` by

1. trying to deliver the file named `cgi-bin`
2. if that fails, looking for a directory called `cgi-bin` (and subsequently for an `index.html` or `index.php` in there)
3. if that also fails to either delivering `index.php` (or an equivalent script) with `cgi-bin` as a parameter or a 404 error